# Tensorflow text tokenizer incorrect tokenization

Tags: tensorflow, keras, text, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to use `TF Tokenizer` for a NLP model

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=200, split=" ")
sample_text = ["This is a sample sentence1 created by sample person AB.CDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 
               "This is another sample sentence1 created by another sample person AB.CDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"]

tokenizer.fit_on_texts(sample_text)

print (tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(["sample person AB.CDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"]))
```

OP:

```
[[1, 7, 8, 9]]
```

Word_Index:

```
print(tokenizer.index_word[8])  ===> 'ab'
print(tokenizer.index_word[9])  ===> 'cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

The problem is that the `tokenizer` creates tokens based on `.` in this case. I am giving the `split = " "` in the `Tokenizer` so I expect the following op:

```
[[1,7,8]], where tokenizer.index_word[8] should be 'ab.cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

As in I want the tokenizer to create `words` based on `space (" ")` and not on any `special characters`

How do I make the `tokenizer` create tokens only on `spaces`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Tokenizer` takes another argument called `filter` which is currently defaults to all ascii punctuations (`` filters='!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\t\n' ``). During tokenization, all of the characters contained in `filter` are replaced by the specified `split` string.

If you will look in the source code of the `Tokenizer` and specifically on the method [fit_on_texts](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/tree/master/keras_preprocessing/text.py#L199-L251), you will see it uses the function [text_to_word_sequence](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/6701f27afa62712b34a17d4b0ff879156b0c7937/keras_preprocessing/text.py#L14) which receive the `filter` characters and consider them the same as the `split` it also receives:

```py
def text_to_word_sequence(... ):
    ...
    translate_dict = {c: split for c in filters}
    translate_map = maketrans(translate_dict)
    text = text.translate(translate_map)

    seq = text.split(split)
    return [i for i in seq if i]
```

So, in order to not split nothing but the specified `split`, just pass empty string to the `filter` argument